# Deferred is not called sometimes (twisted python)

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I've done a quite simple web service like this:

```
class UploadResource(Resource):

    def onSuccess(self, result):
        self.request.write("OK")

    def onError(self, result):
        self.request.write("Error")

    def render_POST(self, request):
        request.data.save_to_disk()
        d = request.mirror("http://mirror_replica/Upload")
        d.addCallbacks(self.onSuccess, self.onError)
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET
```

Method `request.mirror()` returns a deferred which fired callbacks after http client request finished send data to another replica of the same web service

When I ran a simple stress test for /Upload method to one replica after some successful requests I got a read timeout client exception.
For 1000 successful requests I'v got one read timeout exception.
After some debug I figured out that sometimes **onSuccess callback never called** and read timeout did not caused by heavy load.

So, I've rewrote class code to this:

```
class UploadResource(Resource):

    def render_POST(self, request):
        request.data.save_to_disk()
        d = request.mirror("http://mirror_replica/Upload")

        def onSuccess(result):
            request.write("OK")

        def onError(self, result):
            request.write("Error")

        d.addCallbacks(onSuccess, onError)
        return server.NOT_DONE_YET
```

Now **`onSuccessCallback` is always called** and read timeout is gone.

**The question is "Why?"**

Comment: In your first example, what's setting `self.request`?

Comment: like this: def render_POST(self, request): self.request = request

Answer (score 1):

If your `Deferred` is not being called, then someone is failing to call it.  This could be a bug, or it could simply be that the request is taking a long time.  Without seeing the code for the `mirror` method it's really impossible to even guess.  If you could produce a [complete, runnable example](http://sscce.org), that would go a long way towards diagnosing your problem.